# How do I properly deallocate memory for a merged LL in the destructor function in c++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I've created a link list class with some operations.

I am trying to merge two linked lists together, as shown in the `main` function. I am able to successfully do that operation and have it display on the screen.

I suspect I may be doing something wrong, though, with implementing the tail node's `next` pointer. When the destructor is called, I turn on the debugger to see what is going on exactly. It deletes all of the nodes successfully and shows that `old->next` and subsequently `head` do end up equaling `nullptr`. I made sure for the destructor to only loop when the empty operation is false for `nullptr`.

But, for some reason, the destructor continues looping and the program gives me the error:

> LinkedList(2000,0x1000d3dc0) malloc: error for object 0x1007239d0: pointer being freed was not allocated

I know the solution may be obvious, but I am completely pooped. The destructor works fine for non-merged lists.

```
class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    friend class LinkedList;
};

class LinkedList{
public:
    Node* head;
public:
    LinkedList()
    {head = nullptr;}
    ~LinkedList()
    {while (!empty()) remove();}
    void addDataBack(int data);
    void display();
    void remove();
    bool empty() const
    {return head == nullptr;}
    void merge(Node* list1, Node* list2);
};

void LinkedList::addDataBack(int data){
    Node *p = new Node;
    Node *t;
    t = head;
    p->data = data;
    p->next = nullptr;
    if (!head){
        head = p;
    }
    else{
        t = head;
        while(t->next){
            t = t->next;
        }
        t->next = p;
    }
}

void LinkedList::display(){
    Node *t = head;
    while (t){
        cout << t->data << endl;
        t = t->next;
    }
}

void LinkedList::remove(){
    Node *old = head;
    head = old->next;
    delete old;
}

void LinkedList::insertNode(int index, int data){
    Node *node = new Node;
    int i = 0;
    Node *t = head;
    Node *p = nullptr;
    node->data= data;
    while ( t!= NULL){
        if (index == i){
            p->next = node;
            node->next = t;
            break;
        }
        p = t;
        t = t->next;
        i++;
    }
}

void LinkedList:: merge(Node *list1, Node *list2){
    Node* t = list1;
    head = list1;
    while (t->next) {
        t = t->next;
    }
    t->next = list2;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    LinkedList list;
    LinkedList list2;
    list.addDataBack(8);
    list.addDataBack(3);
    list.addDataBack(7);
    list.addDataBack(12);
    list.addDataBack(9);
    list.insertNode(2, 25);
    list2.addDataBack(4);
    list2.addDataBack(10);
    LinkedList list3;
    list3.merge (list.head, list2.head);
    list.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The code does not compile because you're missing the insert function prototype in the class definition.
- See the insertNode function; in the line `p->next = node`, if index
  is 0, then this line is going to indirect a null pointer and throw an exception.
- The insertNode function will **leak memory** if you provide an index outside the current number of nodes - 1
- The insertNode function will **leak memory** if the current list is empty

Here is how it should look.

```
void LinkedList::insertNode(int index, int data) 
{
  Node* newNode = new Node;
  newNode->data = data;

  //Wrap this up quick if the list is already empty. 
  if (head == nullptr)
  {
    head = newNode;
    return;
  }

  int i = 0;
  Node* current = head;
  Node* prev = nullptr;
  while (current != nullptr)
  {
    if (index == i)
    {
      newNode->next = current;

      if (prev)
        prev->next = newNode;

      return;
    }
    prev = current;
    current = current->next;
    i++;
  }
  //if (index >= i)

    //Either delete the new node, or throw an out of bounds exception.
    //Otherwise this will result in a memory leak. Personally, I think 
    //throwing the exception is correct.
    delete newNode;
}
```

### Here is the main issue:

Your merge function is a bit confusing, because you are essentially creating a new list from two lists, but not via a constructor, but simply merging them. This will mean that list1 is functionally equivalent to list3, but the addresses are all intermingled. **This means that when we exit the main function scope, you will be deleting memory from list1, and then when it destroys list2 it will ALSO delete them again, and list3 will do the same** (though it will have crashed before then).

Why not simply make it take one list and then merge the two?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    friend class LinkedList;
};
class LinkedList{
public:
    Node* head;
public:
    LinkedList()
    {head = nullptr;}
    ~LinkedList();
    void addDataBack(int data);
    void display();
    void remove();
    void insertNode(int index, int data);
    bool empty() const
    {return head == nullptr;}
    void merge(LinkedList& otherList);
};
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
  while (!empty())
    remove();
}
void LinkedList::addDataBack(int data){
    Node *p = new Node;
    Node *t;
    t = head;
    p->data = data;
    p->next = nullptr;
    if (!head){
        head = p;
    }
    else{
        t = head;
        while(t->next){
            t = t->next;
        }
        t->next = p;
    }
}
void LinkedList::display(){
    Node *t = head;
    while (t){
        cout << t->data << endl;
        t = t->next;
    }
}
void LinkedList::remove(){
    Node *old = head;
    head = old->next;

    delete old;
    old = nullptr;
}
    void LinkedList::insertNode(int index, int data) 
{
  Node* newNode = new Node;
  newNode->data = data;

  //Wrap this up quick if the list is already empty. 
  if (head == nullptr)
  {
    head = newNode;
    return;
  }

  int i = 0;
  Node* current = head;
  Node* prev = nullptr;
  while (current != nullptr)
  {
    if (index == i)
    {
      newNode->next = current;

      if (prev)
        prev->next = newNode;

      return;
    }
    prev = current;
    current = current->next;
    i++;
  }
  //if (index >= i)

    //Either delete the new node, or throw an out of bounds exception.
    //Otherwise this will result in a memory leak. Personally, I think 
    //throwing the exception is correct.
    delete newNode;

}
void LinkedList:: merge(LinkedList& otherList){
    Node* thisTail = head;
    while (thisTail->next) {
        thisTail = thisTail->next;
    }

    thisTail->next = otherList.head;
    otherList.head = nullptr;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    LinkedList list;
    LinkedList list2;
    list.addDataBack(8);
    list.addDataBack(3);
    list.addDataBack(7);
    list.addDataBack(12);
    list.addDataBack(9);
    list.insertNode(2, 25);
    list2.addDataBack(4);
    list2.addDataBack(10);
    list.merge(list2);
    list.display();
    list2.display();
    cout << "list2 is " << (list2.empty() ? "empty." : "not empty");

    return 0;
}
```

### Final Note:

Try to avoid single letter variables unless they are used for iteration, otherwise (especially with linked lists and pointer juggling) it is very difficult to maintain, debug and receive help for.

Comment: lol i deleted the insert prototype while cleaning up to post here by accident. And hmm, that makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks, I updated a few more times to take care of a few memory leaks I noticed.

Comment: Is there anyway I can do it by having it merged into a new linked list??

Comment: You would need to make what is called a "deep copy" or a clone of the two lists you want to merge.This means that for each node in list1 and list2, you must allocate a new node which copies the data from each respective node in list1 and list2, and link them together in the middle. This prevents the LinkedList objects from owning each others pointers and attempting to delete them while other lists still use them.

A constructor would make the most sense, but a merge function (while the name may be confusing) would work just as well. Here's a tut  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHpS2TBfWQg

Comment: And if you don't want to use a deep copy, I suggest using a different data structure all together, or use the STL's smart pointer library in some terrible and complicated way.

Answer (score -1):

> But, for some reason, the destructor continues looping and [...]

I doubt that, but this is what might appear to be happening if you are not watching closely enough (in particular, watching the value of the `this` pointer). It looks to me as though the destructor of `list3` will finish looping, at which point the destructor of `list2` will start (destroying in the opposite order of construction). If you miss seeing this transition, it could very well look like the destructor is continuing when it is in fact being called a second time.

Since you never changed `list2.head`, it is still pointing at one of the nodes that had been merged into `list3`. When `list2`'s destructor starts, `head` is still pointing at one of the nodes that had just been deleted by `list3`'s destructor. Trying to delete that already-deleted node is an error.